# Refactor a case structure in a controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following code in a controller. Obviously it screams for refactoring. But I don't know how to tackle it. How can refactor it so that all the duplicated code parts go away?

```
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, social_media_account} ->
    case social_media_account.provider do
      "Twitter" ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, gettext("A"))
        |> redirect(to: user_social_media_account_path(conn, :index, conn.assigns[:user]))
      "GitHub" ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, gettext("B"))
        |> redirect(to: user_social_media_account_path(conn, :index, conn.assigns[:user]))
      _ ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, gettext("C"))
        |> redirect(to: user_social_media_account_path(conn, :index, conn.assigns[:user]))
    end
  {:error, changeset} ->
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a value from `case` and use that:

```
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, social_media_account} ->
    info = case social_media_account.provider do
      "Twitter" ->
        gettext("A")
      "GitHub" ->
        gettext("B")
      _ ->
        gettext("C")
    end
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, info)
    |> redirect(to: user_social_media_account_path(conn, :index, conn.assigns[:user]))
  {:error, changeset} ->
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```